Loading traced pytorch model to C++
Will be grateful for any help :(
I'm having a problem with using pytorch pretrained model in C++ via TorchLib. I've added Torchlib to Cmake and it successfully downloads the model and works until line:
at::Tensor output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();

After this line it crushes with the error: INTEL MKL ERROR: The specified module could not be found. mkl_avx2.1.dll. Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_avx2.1.dll or mkl_def.1.dll.  and I didn't figured out what is wrong with TorchLib here.
The whole code is here:
#include <torch/script.h>
...
    string path = "traced_energynn_model.pt";
    torch::jit::script::Module module;
    try {
        // Deserialize the ScriptModule from a file using torch::jit::load().
        module = torch::jit::load(path);
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& e) {
        std::cerr << "error loading the model\n";
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Model traced_energynn_model loaded fine\n";

    // Create a vector of inputs.
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(torch::randn({ 2 }));

    // Execute the model and turn its output into a tensor.
    at::Tensor output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();
    std::cout << output << "\n";

Seems like the problem is with some part of the lib related to python, but it's strange because the model loads to C++ by LibTorch successfully.
